# How to convert datetime column to dd/mm/yyyy format in R

Tags: r

I have a dataframe consisting 4 columns:

```
ID      Name       response      datetime
a-1     abc        xyz           2020-01-05 00:00:00
a-2     abc        xyz           2020-01-06 00:00:00
a-3     abc        xyz           2020-01-07 00:00:00
```

I want to convert only datetime column to dd/mm/yyyy format:

Required Result:

```
ID      Name       response      datetime
a-1     abc        xyz           05/01/2020
a-2     abc        xyz           06/01/2020
a-3     abc        xyz           07/01/2020
```

I have tried this:

```
df2<-mutate(df,as.Date(as.POSIXct(df$datetime, format="%d-%m-%Y")))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to first convert your timestamp string to POSIXct using the `strptime` function.  Then, convert that POSIXct to a string in the format you want using `strftime`:

```
dt <- "2020-01-05 00:00:00"
x <- strptime(dt, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
out <- strftime(x, "%d/%m/%Y")
out
[1] "05/01/2020"
```

For a one-liner, which will work on your actual dataframe, use:

```
df$datetime <- strftime(strptime(df$datetime, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"), "%d/%m/%Y")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, How to pass it to entire dataframe?